# The method 'startPayment' isn't defined for the type 'PayUCheckoutProFlutter'

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, payu

in code The method 'startPayment' isn't defined for the type 'PayUCheckoutProFlutter'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'startPayment'.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:payu_checkoutpro_flutter/payu_checkoutpro_flutter.dart';

class MyClass extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyClassState createState() => _MyClassState();
}

class _MyClassState extends State<MyClass> implements PayUCheckoutProProtocol {
  late PayUCheckoutProFlutter _checkoutPro;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _checkoutPro = PayUCheckoutProFlutter(this);
  }
```

this method i use

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('PayU Checkout Pro'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          child: Text("Make Payment"),
          onPressed: () async {
            String orderId = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString();
            String amount = "1";

            var response = await _checkoutPro.startPayment( // here show this error in startPaymnet
              orderId: orderId,
              amount: amount,
              productInfo: 'iPhone 12',
              merchantKey: 'your_merchant_key',
              userPhoneNumber: '9999999999',
              transactionId: orderId,
              firstName: 'Orange',
              merchantSalt: 'your_merchant_salt',
              email: 'test@example.com',
              hashUrl: '',
              userCredentials: '',
            );

            // Handle the response
            if (response['status'] == 'success') {
              handlePaymentSuccess(amount);
            } else if (response['status'] == 'failed') {
              handlePaymentFailure(amount, response['message']);
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  generateHash(Map response) {
    // Implement the logic to generate the hash using the response received from your backend server
    // Pass the generated hash to the SDK using _checkoutPro.hashGenerated(hash: hashResponse);
    // Example:
    Map<String, String> hashResponse = {
      'hashName': 'paymentHash',
      'hash': 'your_generated_hash_here',
    };
    _checkoutPro.hashGenerated(hash: hashResponse);
  }

  @override
  onPaymentSuccess(dynamic response) {
    // Handle the payment success response
  }

  @override
  onPaymentFailure(dynamic response) {
    // Handle the payment failure response
  }

  @override
  onPaymentCancel(Map? response) {
    // Handle the payment cancel response
  }

  @override
  onError(Map? response) {
    // Handle the error response
  }

  void handlePaymentSuccess(String amount) {
    // Handle payment success logic
  }

  void handlePaymentFailure(String amount, String message) {
    // Handle payment failure logic
  }
```

how to slove this error whats a method for startPayment for call payment function.
payu_checkoutpro_flutter depedancy use is right for payu payment gateway?

Comment: try to use latest version of wrapper for payu.https://pub.dev/packages/payu_checkoutpro_flutter/  they are using openCheckoutScreen  in their example